Why does \node work inside an axis environment while \pgfpointanchor fails?
Consider the following code, where a node named A is defined inside an axis environment at the end of an \addplot macro.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 1)} node[pos = .5, sloped, above] (A) {to};
    % Does not work here
    % \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{south east}}
    \node[rotate = 0, red] at (A) {YO};
  \end{axis}
  % Works here
  % \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{south east}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The low-level pgf command \pgfpointanchor does work outside of axis environment but does not work inside (the error I get is No shape named A is known). If I understand correctly, this is not surprising since pgfplots needs to process all the plots to compute the dimensions of the axis and then determine the coordinates of the node.
What I don't understand is why the \node at (A) command works inside the axis environment. Could someone explain this behavior?
